# How to tell if the model is new in the template?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js

I'd like to display specific elements in my template if my model is new vs existing.

I tried to show `{{ id }}`, `{{ cid }}` and `{{ isNew }}` but all of them are empty.

Here's the examples :

```
// The Model
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

// In the view
var model = new Contact();
this.$el.empty().append(this.template(model.toJSON()));

// The template :
{{#if isNew}}New model{{/if}}
```

How can I test ?

Comment: Need far more background to answer this. Where and how is your model defined? Where is it coming from? How are the properties defined? What template engine are you using?

Comment: My needs are pretty straightforward. I updated the question but I doubt you will find more help in it. But that's why I do (my model is simple, the view and template too).

Comment: Looking at the code from Backbone/Github, only attributes are pushed, without id/cid. So I have no way, in the template, to know if the model is new or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I come up with :

```
// The Model
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    'toJSON': function () {
    // Copied from the source
    var obj = _.clone(this.attributes);

    obj['isNew'] = this.isNew();
    return obj;
    }
});
```

Of course, this ensure that this model does not have the attribute "isNew" ;)

Comment: +1...  I also wonder if `<%= typeof id == "undefined" %>` would work, since in theory, the id only exists after the model has been synced to the server.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. I think it depends on if you wait on the server or not?

Comment: The downside of using `toJSON` like this is that Backbone will use `toJSON` to serialize your model for the server and the server might not be too happy about seeing `isNew`. I've been leaning towards a separate method for serializing models for views, that leaves `toJSON` and `parse` for server communication and this other method (which calls `toJSON` by default) for views. Anyway, this is cleaner IMO than looking for `id` side effects.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding the server side effect, interesting!

Comment: I think the above should be entirely equivalent to checking `isNew` (without the possible side effects of overriding `toJSON` mentioned by mu.  See the docs on `isNew`:  http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew

Comment: I first checked my answer since it's the only one, but what you say @mu-is-too-short is interesting, if you add an answer, I'll accept yours.

Comment: Your answer is fine, my comment is more of an FYI than anything else. There's nothing wrong with adjusting `toJSON`, you just need to know about its dual purpose.